# QUnit: #qunit-fixture and surprising results

Tags: jquery, qunit

I have following problem:

I want to test simple JQuery code using QUnit.

```
// code allows selection of all checkboxes inside form using .select-all checkbox     
$(function() {
      $(".select-all").click(function() {
        if (this.checked)
          $(".robject").prop("checked", true);
        else
          $(".robject").prop("checked", false);
      })
})
```

The problem is when I put my form inside `<div id="qunit-fixture></div>` (**reason**: more tests in the future) I get assertion error:

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Javascript tests</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qunit/2.4.0/qunit.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="qunit">
  </div>
  <div id="qunit-fixture">
    <form>
      <input type="checkbox" class="select-all">
      <input type="checkbox" class="robject r_1" name="" value="">
      <input type="checkbox" class="robject r_2" name="" value="">
      <input type="checkbox" class="robject r_3" name="" value="">
      <button type="button" name="button">Delete</button>
    </form>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qunit/2.4.0/qunit.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    QUnit.test("start all unchecked, then check all", function (assert) {
      assert.equal($('.robject:checked').length, 0);
      $('.select-all').click();
      assert.equal($('.robject:checked').length, 3);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is error:

> Expected: 3, Result: 0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to programatically to inject html to qunit-fixture and after that to write assertions. 
So for example:

```
QUnit.test("start all unchecked, then check all", function (assert) {
    var fixture = $( "#qunit-fixture" );
    fixture.append( "<form>addd your form here</form>" );

    assert.equal($('.robject:checked').length, 0);
    $('.select-all').click();
    assert.equal($('.robject:checked').length, 3);
});
```